# Installing PHP on Server 2008 R2 and IIs 7.0

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

Followed [these instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php) to install PHP.

- Downloaded and extracted PHP-5.5.34-nts-Win32-VC11-x86 to C:\PHP. 
  Created the PHP.ini file and turn on/off the directives listed there.

Then followed [these steps](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php)

- Used ServerManager to install CGI on the Web Server (IIs) Role Used
- IIS Server Manager to create the handler mapping which points to my
  installation.
- Wasn't in the instructions but I Restarted the server using the Manage Server pane.

I created a basic html page with  in it, named it hello.php and put it on the server.

I keep getting **500 Internal server error**. I'm pretty new to all of this and not sure how to track down the problem or test for where the problem is. (Most likely behind the keyboard!)

Any advice or tips on getting this to work?

Comment: You rebooted your server after the installation?

Comment: I reset and stopped/started the webserver. Or do you mean the actual machine (in my case a virtual machine)?

Comment: I mean the machine....

Comment: Done. No difference. I also thought it might be because I turned off anonymous authentication, but I tried that too and no difference.

Comment: Ah I found this thread http://serverfault.com/questions/613927/500-error-on-fresh-install-of-iis-and-php. I hadn't installed the VC++11 runtime. When browsing the page from the server box (not my local machine) I got a more complete error message that lead me to that thread. Thank you for your help.